# Security - Use chrome extensions only for development

Tags: google-chrome, security, google-chrome-extension, privileges

I am using chrome for web development and as my main browser. I have installed some extensions that I am using only for development like [JSONView](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?hl=en).

In most cases such kind of extensions requiring some extra permissions, like

`Read and change all your data on the websites you visit`

Is there any way to separate use of this extensions only for development and not use when I am logged in in something personal. So even if some extension will want still some personal data, that will not be possible.

Comment: Use multiple Chrome profiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use multiple Chrome profiles.

Each profile has its own data and its own set of extensions.
As long as you don't install any extensions that can access the filesystem, they're completely separate.